# Blackberry webworks SDK for OS 7 and earlier

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I want to develope phonegap app for BB OS7 and earlier but need to get webworks sdk. Blackberry website has only for BB 10. Is webworks for BB10 also support other versions ? if not where to get older versions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the page, where you can download Webworks SDK for BlackBerry OS (RIM OS):

http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/download/

Answer (score 2):

This may be a super late answer, but it's not recommended to use Phonegap for anything < BB10. I would use the webworks sdk natively - it's not much different from phonegap and you can pretty much have both formats in one project with separate config.xml files if your app doesn't rely a lot on hardware interaction. I recently built a simple application and on Blackberry OS6 the phonegap version would barely run but the webworks version works great.

Answer (score 2):

although very late but think it might help. [Developing for blackberry using webworks](http://techbirds.in/?p=495)